# Is there a way to flatten this promise chain more effectively (involves chaining on catch)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Assume a function returning a custom promise. For the sake of this example, lets just assume a custom promise is needed:

**(Note: the environment is AngularJS [i.e. 1.x] that does ES5)**

```
function doMyFunction() {
   var d = $q.defer();
   do1()
   .then (function () { return do2(); }) //P1
   .then (function () { return do3(); }) // P2
   .then {function () {console.log ("All good"); d.resolve(true); return d.promise;}) // P3
   .catch (function () { 
        console.log ("Oh no"); 
        fallback1()
        .then (function () {
             console.log ("Ah this fallback1 worked");
             d.resolve(true);
             return d.promise;
        }, function () { 
            console.log ("Oh no, fallback failed, do I have to go through nested hell to now try fallback 2?");
           d.resolve(false);
           return d.promise;
       });
     return d.promise;
}
```

As describe above, I am trying to try different approaches in sequence, only if the former approach fails.

If I try and flatten it like so:

```
// lets start from the last promise above

.then {function () {console.log ("All good"); d.resolve(true); return d.promise;}) // P3
.catch (function () { return fallback1(); })
.then (function () { d.resolve(true); return d.promise; }) // P4
.catch (function () {})
```

This doesn't really work, because P4 is executed when P3 succeeds as well.

What is a good approach to handle a case where I need to try multiple promise based functions in sequence and only if the previous one fails?

Also, I'm not sure if I can really do `.then().catch().then().catch()`

Is there a clean approach to avoid nesting hell in such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain `catch` method calls, as `catch` also returns a promise which can be either resolved or rejected. So you would actually perform the next fallback within the `catch` callback:

```js
function perform(i) { // Some mock function for this demo returning a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('try with ' + i);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (i < 4) reject("some error"); else resolve(i);
        }, 100);
    });
}

function doMyFunction() {
    return perform(1)
        .catch( () => perform(2) )
        .catch( () => perform(3) )
        .catch( () => perform(4) ) // <-- this is the first one that resolves
        .catch( () => perform(5) ) // <-- this callback is never executed
        .catch( () => perform(6) ); // <-- (idem)
}

doMyFunction().then( (i) => console.log('Success with step ' + i) ); // <-- final result
```

Note that with ES5 code under AngularJS, the first mock function would look like this:

```
function perform(i) { // Some function returning a promise
    var d = q$.defer();
    console.log('try with ' + i);
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (i < 4) d.reject("some error"); else d.resolve(i);
    }, 100);
    return d.promise();
}
```

#### Combined with other handlers

If your logic has other handlers in between, you could use the above principle in a function and just call that function providing it all possible fallbacks:

```js
function perform(i) { // Some mock function for this demo returning a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('try with ' + i);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (i < 4) reject("some error"); else resolve(i);
        }, 100);
    });
}

function tryAndFallback(fallbacks) {
    return (function loop(fallbacks) {
        if (!fallbacks.length) return Promise.reject("Nothing worked!");
        return fallbacks[0]().catch( () => loop(fallbacks.slice(1)) );
    })(fallbacks);
}

function doMyFunction() {
    return Promise.resolve() // <-- some promise that is just fine
        // Now a task that has a few fallbacks
        .then( () => tryAndFallback([() => perform(2),  
                                     () => perform(3),
                                     () => perform(4)]) )
        .then( () => console.log('more work can be done here') );
}

doMyFunction().then( (i) => console.log('All done') ); // <-- final result
```

Comment: Could the downvoter be so kind to explain what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks trincot. My issue is not about chaining catch calls, but the fact that in the first catch, I do another function that can return success or throw another exception and how to flatten that if I have many fallbacks to try (FYI I did not downvote)

Comment: Yeah. Someone went nuts with the downvotes on this page.

Comment: @user1361529, I thought my solution did just that -- it is flat, and tries fallbacks until there is a success, and then it returns that success as promised value. Isn't that what you are after?

Comment: I think OP should clarify the question, I'm not sure about what he is looking for

Comment: @trincot, ah I see what you mean - I might have misinterpreted. Good point - let me fit this into my code and I'll update

Comment: @trincot - I cleared my head. If you see the original example, my issue is not with catch chaining, but the fact that there are successful handlers in between. See P3 in flattened code, it returns success. After P3 is a catch, that works. But after the catch, there is another success handler (.then) - this will get called even if the previous catch was not executed. That is my flattening problem.

Comment: In that case I would write a utility function that can deal with the fallback mechanism separately. So you would call that function whenever you have fallbacks, but you could use it right in the middle of a promise chain. See addition section I added to my answer. I used ES6, as it works in a snippet, but it is of course the same principle with `$q`.

Comment: Thanks - yes, using an intermediary function and structuring it the way you have proposed does work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into async/await for javascript? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Verify browser compatibility is acceptable.

```
async function() {
  let first, second, third, fourth;
  try {
    first = await do1();
    second = await do2();
    third = await do3();
    fourth = await do4();
    return fourth;
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e + ' failed. Reverting back to the first')
  }

  return first;
}
```

I wonder. Untested, but since they are all undefined, if you want to return only the last accepted item then you can test the following final return after the catch as this:

```
return fourth || third || second || first;
```

It should only return the first valid result which would be the final result that had an acceptable value.

Comment: Thanks. The code I posted was for angularJS which does ES5 - my apologies that I did not explicitly call that out. Looking at https://labs.magnet.me/nerds/2015/11/16/async-await-in-angularjs.html it looks like this is not natively supported. I've updated my original post with an additional note about this.

Comment: Ah yes. Good ol' angularjs. That has caught me up in the past. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Is there a reason why this has been downvoted? When I originally posted this there was no requirement on ES-spec. Since then. the OP requested to be inline with AngularJS and ES5. This is fine, and my answer is no longer valid with his/her question but is that a reason for down voting? If there is something else that is amiss, I'd like to hear to improve upon my own understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Proper promises chaining should look like following

```
function doWholeWork(){
return work1().
then((work1Result)=>{
return work2();
})
then((work2Result)=>{
return work3();
})
.catch(error=>{
console.log("Some error happened", error)
});
}
```

Comment: Define "proper". My code does what you have done, with the addition of custom promises, which I said I need - - please re-read the context of my post. (FYI, I did not downvote)

Comment: Oh so you want to proceed if previous fails.. Sorry I misread that. trincot's amswer seems to be doing the work, isn't it?